# How to randomise word spacing in a paragraph?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a panel of words that are distributed unevenly.

Here's a very basic sample image:

[image: random word panel]

Using text-align and word-spacing I have come close..

```css
body {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 50px auto 0;
}
p {
  background: lightgrey;
  padding: 2em;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  word-spacing: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}
p span {
  font-size: 1em;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<p>one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve thirteen fourteen <span>fifteen</span> sixteen seventeen eighteen nineteen twenty</p>
```

However I'd like to randomise the spacing between words. Is this possible with CSS? I'm open to changing the HTML, but these panels are dynamically generated and could have any number of words.

Any suggestions?

[Codepen for those who prefer](http://codepen.io/sol_b/pen/xgaJze)

Comment: I am afraid such thing using only css is not achievable.

Comment: If you add javascript to the mix you can generate series of random numbers and loop through them adding n spaces in each loop

Comment: @Bardo Thanks for the suggestion. I thought that might be the case. I'll keep playing with the CSS for a bit longer and see if I get anywhere..

Comment: If you are open for js solutions tag your question with js.

Comment: @NenadVracar Thanks, done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use `white-space: pre-wrap` on your element and js to generate random number of white-spaces between each word.

```js
var min = 1;
var max = 15;
var newText = $('p').html().replace(/\s/g, function() {
  return " ".repeat(parseInt(Math.random() * (max - min) + min))
});
$('p').html(newText)
```

```css
body {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 50px auto 0;
}
p {
  background: lightgrey;
  padding: 2em;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
p span {
  font-size: 1em;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve thirteen fourteen <span>fifteen</span> sixteen seventeen eighteen nineteen twenty</p>
```

Comment: Thanks. Both answers I received worked, however I think this is an elegant method and answers the question more directly.

Answer (score 3):

Use JS to generate random position on page. I made simply random position, you can use more complex algorithm

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var texts = $('p').text().split(' ');

  $('p').text('');
  $.each(texts,
    function() {
      $('p').append(
        $('<span>', {
          text: this,
          "class": this == 'fifteen' ? 'active' : '',
          css: {
            left: Math.floor(Math.random() * $('p').width()),
            top: Math.floor(Math.random() * $('p').height()),
            fontSize: Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 10
          }
        })
      );
    });
});
```

```css
p {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
}
p span {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #555;
}

p span.active {
  color: #00aaff;
  font-weight: bold;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve thirteen fourteen fifteen sixteen seventeen eighteen nineteen twenty</p>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great. I like how it changes vertical alignment too (which I didn't even ask for). If I can't find anything with CSS I'll implement something like this. It might be cool to adjust the algorithm to change font size too. Thanks again

Comment: Thank you for the updated code with font size change. This is a great solution, however I chose the other answer as it is slightly simpler and closer to the question asked. Cheers